# vue js event bus calls few events

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus

I'm struggling with event bus.
I have a list of notes I display on home ('/'). I use the event bus to update the array when in 3 different places - when deleting, creating or updating a new note.
After using different options(delete+create, create+update...) the functions that are triggered by the event listener are triggered few times, creating duplicate items or deleting more than it should.
I am using one event bus for all of them.
I am using $once and I have placed it on the created hook.

How can I see what's in the event bus and how can I clear it after using it?

```js
//event bus def
var eventBus = new Vue();
export default eventBus;

//the main page, where notes being displayed
  template: `
    <div>
    <h1>this is the home page</h1>
    
        <div class="note-container" v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
        
            <component :noteData="note" :is="note.type" class="note" :style="note.style"></component>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            notes: []
        }
    }, 
    created() {
        eventBus.$once('noteAdded', data => {
            var newNotes = notesService.createNewNote(data)          
            this.notes = newNotes;
            console.log('created activated');
            
        })
        eventBus.$once('noteUpdated', note=>{
            notesService.updateNote(note)
            .then(updatedNotes=>{
                this.notes=updatedNotes
               console.log('update activated');  
            })
        })
        eventBus.$once('noteDeleted', note=>{
            notesService.deleteNote(note)
            .then(notes=>{
                console.log('delete activated');
                this.notes=notes
            })
        })
        
//where update is being called from
template: `
    <div>
    <form>
    some form
        </form>
        <button  @click="handleUpdate">Update</button>
       
    </div>   `,
     methods:{
        handleUpdate(){
            eventBus.$emit('noteUpdated', this.note)     
            this.$router.push('/')   
            console.log('handle img');
            
            
            
        },
    }
    
    //where create is being called from
      handleSubmit(){
            eventBus.$emit('noteAdded', this.data)     
            this.$router.push('/')
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

usually, `eventBus.$off('event')` should turn the event off.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#vm-off

https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Tried to set it to "on" instead of "once" and then use "off", didn't work for me.
Is there any way I can see what events are stored in it?

Comment: you can `console.trace()` inside the $on callback function to see which componnt was triggering the event

Comment: to prevent executing tha callback function on, try adding `if(eventBus.eventName){return;}` to the beginning of your callback function: `eventBus.$once('noteAdded', data => {
            if(eventBus.noteAdded){return;}                                                      
            var newNotes = notesService.createNewNote(data)          
            this.notes = newNotes;
            console.log('created activated');
            
        })`

Comment: trace shows as if it's being called from the same place. I'm getting few of those:
notesService.deleteNote.then.notes @ home-page.js:46
Promise.then (async)  
eventBus.$once.note @ home-page.js:43
on @ vue.js:2471
Vue.$emit @ vue.js:2538
handleDelete @ todo-edit.cmps.js:69
invoker @ vue.js:2029
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.js:1828

adding the condition didn't work either. 
any other ideas or maybe it will be a better idea to assume the problem is somewhere else in the code?
thanks

Comment: do you generate the component more than one time? if you have a few same components- all of them will trigger q react to the event, and it will get fired more than once. component can also get duplicated if your using v-if on it. in this case , again, adding to the beginning of the function `if(eventBus.eventName){return;}` can be helpful.

Comment: setting the condition + adding eventBus.$off() for everything solved the problem. Thank you